# How can get intl.formatMessage from parent component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I get intl.formatMessage from parent component? I wrapped parent component with injectIntl and want send intl.formatMessage to child component. Can someone help me with that? Thank you!

**Parent component**

```
import Car from "./test3";
import { injectIntl } from "react-intl";

class Intl extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Who lives in my garage?</h1>
        <Car brand="Ford" />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default injectIntl(Intl);
```

**Child component**

```
import { FormattedMessage} from "react-intl";

class Car extends React.Component {
  yearsTranslation = () =>
    this.props.intl.formatMessage({ id: "search.filter.maturity.years" });
  render() {
    return <h2>Hello {this.yearsTranslation()}!</h2>;
  }
}

export default Car;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just pass the prop down, like so :

```
class Intl extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Who lives in my garage?</h1>
        <Car brand="Ford" intl={this.props.intl}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default injectIntl(Intl);
```

Answer (score 0):

I thinks `intl` is available in the context. Please check the documentation.